# Good text on quantum groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, reference-request, quantum-groups

I'm interested in learning about quantum groups about a $C^*$-algebraic perspective.

I'm familiar with (the basics) of topology, abstract algebra, measure theory, functional analysis (in particular $C^*$-algebras) and category theory.

However I don't know much about related topics like Hopf-algebras etc.

What references can you recommend and in what order should I read them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have never seen anything about Hopf algebras I recommend perhaps looking at Section 2.2 of [my own thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.09357.pdf). It is a very leisurely introduction in the technically easy finite dimensional case.

Perhaps for a first look at $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebraic quantum groups these notes of Roland Vergnioux might be a good idea:

- *[Haar integrals on finite and compact quantum group](https://vergniouxr.users.lmno.cnrs.fr/fichiers/M2.pdf)*

These notes really well-motivate the definition and relate the definition very well to the commutative situation.

> **An overarching reference might be:
>    - Thomas Timmermann, *An Invitation to Quantum Groups and Duality - From Hopf Algebras to Multiplicative Unitaries and Beyond***

However perhaps use this as a reference and instead look at graduate lecture notes such as (in no particular order):

- Teo Banica, *[Free Quantum Groups and Related Topics](https://teobanica.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/fat.pdf)*
- Adam Skalski, *[Quantum Symmetry Groups and Related Topics](https://www.impan.pl/~skalski/Metabief.pdf)*
- Amaury Freslon, *[Introduction to compact matrix quantum groups and their combinatorics](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~freslon/Documents/M2/M2_Quantum_Groups.pdf)*
- Moritz Weber, *[Introduction to compact (matrix) quantum groups
  and Banica–Speicher (easy) quantum groups](https://www.ias.ac.in/public/Volumes/pmsc/127/05/0881-0933.pdf)*
- Uwe Franz, Adam Skalski, Piotr Soltan, *[Introduction to compact and discrete quantum groups](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.10766.pdf)*

Between these you are in good nick.

Comment: Thanks! This will definitely help!

Comment: @user745578 I wouldn't be shy of reading papers either, especially older papers of Woronowicz and Van Daele. Personally I really like the (old) paper of Kac and Paljutkin but again that is from the finite pov.

Comment: Don't you think those papers are a little too advanced to start with?

Comment: @user745578 I didn't say to start with those papers.

Comment: @user745578 ooooh this is nice: https://www.math.uni-sb.de/ag/speicher/weber/SnapshotQuantumSymmetryMoritzWeber2019.pdf

Comment: I feel that most of the pdf's you linked to have in common that they ommit a lot of proofs. Are you perhaps aware of more complete lecture notes/books that develop the theory of quantum group from scratch (may assume locally compact group theory and operator algebraic techniques)? I know the book quantum groups and duality but I find it sometimes hard to read. Thanks!

Comment: @user745578 hmmm... what might be an example of a proof that you would like to have but don't have.

Comment: Hi, the first link (to the wordpress) is broken

Comment: @user745578 you'll find the same document here: https://banica.u-cergy.fr/