# Classification of non-commutative, non-cocommutative Hopf algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, examples-counterexamples, hopf-algebras

**1. Context**
Apparently, Sweedler's Hopf algebra (presented in 1969) was the first known example of a non-commutative, non-cocommutative Hopf algebra.

More generally, the $N^2$-dimensional Taft-Hopf algebra $H_{N^{2}}$ (introduced in 1971) yields a non-commutative, non-cocommutative Hopf algebra for every positive integer $N \neq 1$ (and an appropriate field). Sweedler's Hopf algebra is simply Taft's Hopf algebra $H_4$ over a field $\mathbb k$ (with $\zeta =-1$ and $char(\mathbb k) \neq 2$).

These examples are more or less from the 1970s. I am wondering what the current state of affairs is.

**2. Questions**

- What other non-commutative, non-cocommutative Hopf algebras are known?
- I skimmed the wikipedia article on the Pareigis Hopf algebra. It seems that it is a further example of a non-commutative and non-cocommutative Hopf algebra. What is its dimension?
- Is there a (complete or partial) classification (up to isomorphism)? What about the subclass of finite-dimensional Hopf algebras?

Comment: I barely know what Hopf algebras are, but typically, classifying a pathological subclass of objects amounts to classifying the whole class. In other words, do you expect the classification of non-commutative, non-cocommutative Hopf algebras to be substantially easier than the classification of Hopf algbras, period?

Comment: @tomasz No, I don't. As you say, they seem pathological. Most Hopf algebras that I know - e.g. group algebras, universal enveloping algebras, tensor algebras - are either cocommutative or commutative. Sweedler‘s Hopf algebra was discovered relatively late, so another reason to guess that it actually is not too easy. However, note that my question has three parts. I’d be happy with another example of a non-commutative, non-cocommutative Hopf algebra. By the way, what makes you say: "Typically, classifying a pathological subclass of objects amounts to classifying the whole class"? Experience?

Comment: Well, the way classification theorems I've seen work, they give you a nice classification of the "well-behaved" objects, usually getting progressively more messy as the objects get more ill-behaved, often to the point of completely eluding classification in general (sometimes, provably so).

Comment: I think the Taft Hopf algebra is telling us something important about the discrete Fourier transform, though I can't quite tell what.

Comment: I think a classification is quite hopeless. Here are some important examples: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_group#Drinfeld%E2%80%93Jimbo_type_quantum_groups

Comment: Gerstenhaber-Voronov https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9409063 showed that the bar construction of a certain kind of $E_2$ algebra is a bialgebra (so this doesn't count as a proper Hopf algebra), these bar constructions are tensor coalgebras (not cocommutative) and the algebra structure comes from the $E_2$ structure on the starting algebra, so it is not generally commutative. Not what you are looking for, I believe, but it seemed relevant.

Comment: @darijgrinberg That seems interesting! Do you remember what? Do you have any reference? At QiaochuYuan and JustinYoung: Thanks a lot.

Comment: @M.C.: I'm saying this mainly because I know the self-duality of the group ring of a cyclic group is tantamount to the basic properties of the Fourier transform, but the Taft Hopf algebra is a more intricate relative of the group ring of the cyclic group, and is also self-dual (for nontrivial reasons, if I remember correctly -- I have never seen it proven).

Comment: I am literally sitting in a talk now with some of these algebras. Another source of algebras is the Benson-Witherspoon algebras, which are a form of smash product.

Comment: I should also mention that if you make connectivity assumptions, then the bar construction bialgebra I mentioned above will be a proper Hopf algebra (existence of antipode is easy), but connected graded Hopf algebras still seem orthogonal to your interest, I only present this as a tangent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where I would look for examples of non-commutative and non-cocommutative Hopf algebras is the world of quantum groups, where you will find many such examples (that also carry a *-involution)

For example,

1. The algebra of functions on the Kac-Paljutkin quantum group (dimension eight).
2. The algebra of functions on a Sekine quantum group (dimension $2n^2$ for a natural number parameter $n$).
3. The algebra of regular functions on Wang's quantum permutation groups, equal to $F(S_N)$ for $N\leq 3$ but infinite dimensional for $N\geq 4$.

To see more examples see the references [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3667937/19352).

I can't answer your second question.

Your third question, perhaps look at the papers of [Andruskiewitsch](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=njyNPt8AAAAJ&hl=en).