Best Introductory Textbooks on Compact & Locally Compact Quantum Groups
This is a soft question / reference request.
I’ve been recently interested in starting research in the area of compact and locally compact quantum groups.  However, I’ve noticed the subject is really dense, and there are tons of prerequisite things to learn / know.
I was wondering if there were any good introductory brief textbooks on the subject that weren’t super massive.

I think this is close to a duplicate, and I give some references there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3665553/good-text-on-quantum-groups

This is what I was looking for, thanks!
